# Java - Iterating over every two elements in a list

Tags: java, iterator

What's the best way to iterate over a list while processing 2 elements at the same time?

Example:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
    String first = strings.get(i);
    String second = null;
    if(strings.size() > i + 1){
        second = strings.get(i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
}
```

Results in:

```
First [item 1] - Second [item 2]
First [item 2] - Second [item 3]
First [item 3] - Second [item 4]
First [item 4] - Second [null]
```

I would like to achieve:

```
First [item 1] - Second [item 2]
First [item 3] - Second [item 4]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just increase `i` by 2 on each iteration, instead of `++` (which increments by 1):

```java
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < strings.size(); i += 2) {
  String first = strings.get(i);
  String second = strings.get(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: can't this go out of bounds?

Comment: What if the list's size is exactly 2? the loop won't iterate over those two elements!

Comment: @IdoSarShalom Hah, classic off by one. Thanks for noticing. Now hopefully fixed.

Answer (score 12):

I created the following method using a Java8 BiConsumer:

```
public static <T> void tupleIterator(Iterable<T> iterable, BiConsumer<T, T> consumer) {
    Iterator<T> it = iterable.iterator();
    if(!it.hasNext()) return;
    T first = it.next();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        T next = it.next();
        consumer.accept(first, next);
        first = next;
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
List<String> myIterable = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
tupleIterator(myIterable, (obj1, obj2) -> {
    System.out.println(obj1 + " " + obj2);
});
```

This will output:

```
1 2
2 3
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to modify and increment `i` for the second value, modify the statement:

```
second = strings.get(i + 1);
```

to

```
second = strings.get(++i);
```

This will increment the `i` as well, since this seems to be the desired behaviour.

So your code would be:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
    String first = strings.get(i);
    String second = null;
    if(strings.size() > i + 1){
        second = strings.get(++i); //Change here
    }
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
}
```

Comment: I would keep changing the index variable only in the for statement's 3rd part. Increasing it in multiple places inside the loop results in less clear (meaning harder to understand and maintain, easier to have bugs) code. This's pretty common idiom / rule of thumb with for loop, and while loop might be better choice, if you do write it your way.

Comment: @hyde, I thought about it, but then decided to change minimum, for the OP's understanding, I agree that for loop counter should be modified in only a single place, since it provides better understanding/readability

Comment: Thanks guys, both answers were really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");    
int i = 0;  
for(; i < strings.size() - 1; i+=2){  
    String first = strings.get(i);  
    String second =  strings.get(i + 1);  
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");  
}  
//For odd sized lists
if(i < strings.size()){         
    System.out.println("First [" + strings.get(i) + "]");  
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you put the `int i = 0` outside the loop?

Comment: @MarcoForberg:Yes.To do the check for odd sized list outside the `for` loop

Comment: hmmm okay, but why not check for odd size "as usual": `strings.size() % 2`? uhmm... correct me if i'm wrong but after execution of the loop i think i will be one greater than the size of the list.

Comment: @MarcoForberg:You could do that as well

Comment: you forgot to set first to a new value in your if block

Answer (score 2):

What if you increase i by 2 in each iteration? Should do...
Otherwise consider increase i inside the actual loop

Answer (score 2):

We should of course provide a solution for the general case ;-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
    for (Pair<Integer> p : Pair.over(list)) {
        System.out.printf("%d, %d\n", p.first, p.second);
    }
}

static class Pair<T> {
    T first;

    T second;

    public Pair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static <T> Iterable<Pair<T>> over(Collection<T> collection) {
        return new PairWise<T>(collection);
    }

    private static class PairWise<T> implements Iterable<Pair<T>>, Iterator<Pair<T>> {

        final Iterator<T> iterator;

        PairWise(Collection<T> collection) {
            super();
            this.iterator = collection.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Pair<T>> iterator() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public Pair<T> next() {
            T first = null;
            T second = null;
            if (iterator.hasNext())
                first = iterator.next();
            else
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            if (iterator.hasNext())
                second = iterator.next();
            return new Pair<T>(first, second);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid indexing with an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html); this works for any [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), not just a list. Just get an iterator and increment it twice per loop iteration:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
Iterator<String> stringsIterator = strings.iterator();
while (stringsIterator.hasNext()) {
  String first = stringsIterator.next();
  String second = stringsIterator.next();
  System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
}
```

This assumes a list of even length, and throws `NoSuchElementException` on the last pass if it's odd length. You can handle this in various ways:

- use a `try`-`catch`;
- have a guard clause that checks that the length is even beforehand;
- check before getting the second element.

Checking the second element:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3");
Iterator<String> stringsIterator = strings.iterator();
while (stringsIterator.hasNext()) {
  String first = stringsIterator.next();
  String second = stringIterator.hasNext() ? stringIterator.next() : null;
  System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
}
```

Iterators confuse some people, so you can also use a for-each loop with a branch and an auxiliary flip-flop variable for parity. This is much worse, since it makes the loop's logic much more complicated to simplify the iteration: rather than the action being done once per pass through the loop, in sequence and without branching, you instead have to go through it twice and branch mentally. Note that this skips the last element if it's of odd length; could add a check of `isFirst` afterwards if want to handle these cases too.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
boolean isFirst = true;
String first = null;
String second = null;
for (String string : strings) {
  if (isFirst) {
    first = string;
    isFirst = false;
  } else {
    second = string;
    isFirst = true;
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
  }
}
```

Lastly, note that all these iterators and auxiliary variables have excess scope (they are only of use for the loop itself, so they pollute the local environment): they could be wrapped in blocks to limit the scope, though usually the resulting nesting is considered worse than the excess scope:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
{
  Iterator<String> stringsIterator = strings.iterator();
  while (stringsIterator.hasNext()) {
    String first = stringsIterator.next();
    String second = stringsIterator.next();
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
  }
}
```

Comment: It’s a basic question, but a clean answer (without indexing) is a bit subtle. This problem arises in real life (and arose for me, which is how I came here), when you have a list of flattened pairs, like `[a0, b0, a1, b1, ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Now in Java 8, by using https://github.com/wapatesh/fig

You can write:

```
seq.forEachSlice(2, (values)->{
    // [1,2]  [3, 4]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
    String first = strings.get(i++);
    String second = null;
    if(strings.size() > i){
        second = strings.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println("First [" + first + "] - Second [" + second + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
    if(i½2 = 0){
        String first = strings.get(i);
        System.out.print("First [" + first + "] ");
    }else{
         String second = strings.get(i + 1);
         System.out.println("- Second [" + second + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I will recommend you to compute the size of the list only one and not create a new string at each new loop.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4");
int length = strings.size();
String first, second = null;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 2){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Opinion: Call to `strings.size()` gets inlined, so performance difference is negligible. Also often (maybe not in this case) optimizations like this have potential to become bugs, when code is changed later, but updating the pre-calculated value is forgotten. It's useful to *consider* this kind of optimization, but it should be done only *if* it is a real improvement in performance (calculating size is expensive, for example) or in readability (size is calculated in several places, for example). Otherwise, like here, it is premature micro-optimization and IMNSHO should be avoided.

Comment: I agree with you that for a first prototype of the solution you don't think about optimization. but in real world situations you deal with large sets of data. So I think it should be considered as a good practice

Comment: "in real world situations you deal with large sets of data" is a bit of a generalisation in my opinion. Large sets of data that require performance optimisations are exceptional, even in real world situations!

Comment: strings.size() will only be evaluated once even without assigning it to a variable... 

You are not "Creating a new string at each loop", you are creating a new local variable reference. Creating of local variable references inside of a loop is not going to hurt performance at all.